# How to reset my game?

Tags: java

What I want is that when ever my player left click(mouse click) in the menuState,
My `init()` method in my `Game Class` must reload. How can i do that???

My game class witn the `init()` method

```
public class Game implements Runnable {

private Display display;
private int width,
            height;
public String title;

private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;

private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

//States
public State gameState;
public MenuState menuState;
public SplashScreen splashscreen;

//Input
private KeyManager keyManager;
private MouseManager mouseManager;

//Camera
private GameCamera gameCamera;

//Handler
private Handler handler;

public Game(String title, int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
    keyManager = new KeyManager();
    mouseManager = new MouseManager();
}

// MY INIT METHOD!!

private void init(){
    display = new Display(title, width, height);
    display.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseListener(mouseManager);
    display.getFrame().addMouseMotionListener(mouseManager);
    display.getCanvas().addMouseListener(mouseManager);
    display.getCanvas().addMouseMotionListener(mouseManager);
    Assets.init();

    handler = new Handler(this);
    gameCamera = new GameCamera(handler, 0, 0);

    gameState = new GameState(handler);
    menuState = new MenuState(handler);
    splashscreen = new SplashScreen(handler);
    State.setState(splashscreen);
}

private void tick(){
    keyManager.tick();

    if(State.getState() != null);
        State.getState().tick();
}

private void render(){
    bs = display.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        display.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    //Clear Screen
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //Draw Here!

    if(State.getState() != null);
        State.getState().render(g);

    //End Drawing!
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
//WHEN THE GAME RUNS, it also runs the intit() method and shows fps and tick

public void run(){

    init();

    int fps = 1000;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    while(running){
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        if(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            render();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        if(timer >= 1000000000){
            System.out.println("Ticks and Frames: " + ticks);
            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }

    }

    stop();

}

public KeyManager getKeyManager(){
    return keyManager;
}

public MouseManager getMouseManager(){
    return mouseManager;
}

public GameCamera getGameCamera(){
    return gameCamera;
}

public int getWidth(){
    return width;
}

public int getHeight(){
    return height;
}

public synchronized void start(){
    if(running)
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    if(!running)
        return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is it you are stuck on? If it is about reseting your game I am pretty sure you already asked a similar question last week https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134277/how-to-make-it-so-when-my-player-dies-the-game-will-restart

Comment: none of those works..

Comment: I guess you meant "I did not manage to make any of them work". Once again, you need to tell us what you tried and did not work, not ask for a piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx Djindjidj for making my doubt clear on what to do

I made a method called `reload()` and in that, I call my asset, game camera and gamestate. And in the tick method i put  `if(handler.getMouseManager().isLeftPressed() && State.getState()==menuState)`
then it calls my `reload()method`

```
private void reload(){
    Assets.init();
    gameState = new GameState(handler);
    gameCamera = new GameCamera(handler, 0, 0);

}

private void tick(){
    if(handler.getMouseManager().isLeftPressed() &&  State.getState()==menuState){
        reload();
    }
```

Comment: I thought you wanted right click ;)

Comment: got confused ;)

Comment: right click closes my game

Answer (score -1):

The more I think about it, the more it gets clear to me that I do not know enough about your code to be able to give you a working answer. Judging from what you write and wrote in the last post, I guess that you do not know much about the framework, either.

It seems to provide you with a static class "State" that you can store the current state of your game into. It is also called in your tick() and your render()-method to call the tick()- and render()-methods of that current state.

I thus guess that each gamestate has its own assets and game logic.
If this is the case, you have two options:

1. check for a right click in your menustate's tick()-method and call a load()-method from there, reinitializing all your assets (similar to my old post below).
2. check for a right click and the menu state in the  tick()-method of the class you provided here and reinitialize the gamestate object.

> You have no dedicated "update"method in your game loop, if not
>   `tick()` is there for that. Anyways, just prompt your mouse / mouse
>   manager for a right button klick in that method and call the init()
>   method.
>
> *Edit:*
>
> I have no idea what framework you are using (I suppose you do use
>   one?), but judging from the last post you made, I can  derive this:
>
> Am I right in supposing that you want the game to restart  when the
>   user clicks the right mouse button while in the menu?
>
> To reset the game, you do not have to reset the display or your
>   handler, you have to reset your game logic and your assets. My first
>   response was thus **false**, you really don't want to call init()
>   again.
>
> To reset your game, add a new function (could be called "load()") that
>   initializes your game assets, score, game logics etc. Anything that is
>   relevant to gameplay, but not to your engine (like the display or your
>   keyboardmanager). If you want to reset the game to a fresh start
>   without restarting the program, you would have to call that function.
>
> To trigger the load function, use your MouseManager() class. From your
>   last post, I can derive that it should have a function called
>   "isRightPressed()".  To restart the game when your right mouse button
>   is clicked and released, do this (for example) in your tick() method:
>
> ```
> if(mouseManager().isLeftPressed() && State.getState()==menuState){ //Don't know if this works, I don't know your menustate and State
> ```
>
> classes 
>         load();
>       } This will reset your game as you provide it in the "load()-method".  You can improve on this by storing the last mouse
>   state and the current to only do this when the right mouse button is
>   released. Else the game will reset each tick as long as you press the
>   right button down. Also, as in the comment, I don't know how you would
>   compare game states in your framework.    Do not forget to update your
>   mousemanager in tick(), too.

Comment: what should I put in the update()` method???

Comment: First part of the answer is more confusing than helpful to me